# Dtrace matched a probe with nothing to display

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, opensuse, dtrace

I'm a beginner to Dtrace. I installed dtrace4linux on my Opensuse. Just wrote a simple command to count the occurrence of kernel stack call.

[image]

But nothing printed really frustrated me. Dtrace is such a platform dependent tool I know it is deeply integrated with FreeBSD, Mac OS, Oracle Linux. I doubt it has something in compatibility with Opensuse. Can anyone figure it out to me. I'm really interested in Dtrace and I want start my journey to Dtrace sooner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Per [the source code](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux/blob/master/driver/dtrace_isa.c#L79), that seems to indicate that you need to have compiled dtrace with the macro `HAVE_STACKTRACE_OPS` defined, and you have to be running on a kernel version of at least 2.6.39.  And the comments in that code lead me to believe dtrace stack tracing on Linux is still more than a bit unstable.